# Common vs Core - difference

Tags: naming, project-structure

Assume we have a couple of libs. What is the difference between **Core** and **Common** library? How should they be recognized and do we organize the responsibilites of both?

```
+Common
  -Class1
+Core
  -Class2
+Lib1 has : Common
+Lib2 has : Core, Common
```

Should **Common** be truely common (i.e. all libs use it)? Or is Common only for those who need it?

What is good practice when refactoring / creating a project?

I don't really understand the difference between Core and Common.

Comment: Good practice: do things that make sense, don't violate the [principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) without a really good reason. You are not feeling the difference because it is an arbitrary decision.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think this depends a lot on your particular application. In a single centralized app, I do think there might be a little overlap between the `Core` and `Common` folders. But the most important thing is that it makes sense for **your** app. Don't feel that you need to have those folders just because you've seen it in other apps...

For me, having a `Core` and a `Common` folders makes a lot of sense in some scenarios - e.g. a web app with an API and a client. You may have your `Core` folder in the API side, where the *core* execution (the business logic) takes place, and then have a `Common` folder with some things you need in both the API and the client sides - e.g., Http requests validation or a Json converter.

Anyway, it may make sense to have a `Core` and a `Common` folder in other kinds of apps.
For example, the `Core` folder would contain those classes that are *central* for your app - the vast majority of business model classes would be there.
In the `Common` folder, on the other hand, you can have some other classes that are shared, but not *central* - e.g., a `Logger` or a `MessageSender` could be there...

As for your little draft of code structure, I think that your `Core` package is the one to be revised - why `Lib1` doesn't use `Core`? If something is *core*, generally it's because everything else needs it in order to run. If you do not have code that is conceptually *central*, maybe you can remove your `Core` package and keep only `Common`?

As for your other question - I do not think the `Common` stuff must be shared by **all** other packages, but just with 2 or more packages sharing something, that can be considered *common*.